# How to scale without deforming / extend shape

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

In my scene, I have prism like shape as seen in the figure below. From the front it looks like a trapezium and from the sides it looks like a parallellogram.

[image: 3D shape]

Now, I want to extend the shape downwards without changing the slope on the sides or the top surface. This would mean that the bottom surface would have to scale on the y (green) axis and would be translated along the x (red) axis depending on how far down the bottom is moved.

What would be a useful workflow for such alterations?

Comment: Just move one of the base faces along the x axis in edit mode.

Comment: @FFeller That will make the front and back end steeper, and will not scale the object downwards.

Comment: Easiest way is using Vertex Slide by pressing G twice in Edit mode with that face selected. To move outside of the mesh boundaries press Alt. This way might not work as expected as sometimes geometry occluded by the one in front can start moving backwards

Comment: @MrZak Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I tried using edge slide, but without alt it will scale it will slide along the plane on the x-axis. Do you have to write an answer or can I close the question otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

One can simply use Edge Slide (with necessary geometry selected press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>) with *Clamp* toggled off (press <kbd>C</kbd> or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while tool is active).